# Is there a Thunderbird add-on that prevents too much email checking?

Tags: thunderbird, timer

I have been looking for a timer, a bit similar to Leechblock for Firefox; I could set it to, say, 30min, meaning that Thunderbird can only be on for 30min a day. The clock would reset everyday.

I had a look around but was unable to find such an extension for Thunderbird. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a copy of Leechblock, and modified its install.rdf to work with Thunderbird. It will now install and run on the latest version of Thunderbird. [Here is a link](http://uppit.com/sw16shd9a4rw/addon-4476-latest.xpi) to my version, which I have tested and found to work on Thunderbird. Since they are both using the Gecko Engine, it should work perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I installed it. But I try to implement a test, to block everything after one minute; it didn't seem to do anything. **What to Block**: I put only a "*" on one line in the domain names to block. **When to block**: All Day, Time limit 1 minutes in every day, Block within time periods AND after time limit, every day. 
Relaunched TB, waited for a couple of minutes, nothing happens.
(It doesn't even block websites opened with Thunderbrowse.)

Could you tell me what settings you used? Thank you!

Comment: @Pat try blocking the incoming/outgoing mail server you are using.

Comment: Not working either. I can still send and retrieve messages (IMAP accounts), even after putting IMAP and SMTP adresses on the blocklist.

Comment: I have no idea then, it may not work perfectly with thunderbird after all. Sorry!